# IE dialogue box to open save save as - Findwindowex api command vba

Tags: vba

I am trying to click Save button in Internet Explorer save as dialogue Box using sendmessage API command.
`Findwindow` command finds the window. However, `FindwindowEx` is not finding the buttons (Open, Save, Save as).

```
Do
    hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "Internet Explorer")
    DoEvents
    Sleep 200
Loop Until hwnd Or Now > timeOut
  
If hwnd Then
        
    SetForegroundWindow hwnd

    hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "Button", vbNullString)
    Debug.Print "   Button "; Hex(hwnd)
 
End If
```

Here is the mage of popup:

[image: image of popup]

Please help...

Comment: What happens, if you send keyboard S there? Looks like S is accelerator for Save action.

Comment: Sorry for late reply...I use Alteryx application to run first and that application runs this excel macro at the end. So Alteryx application screen being at the front, send keys is not working. I have to find a way to send command directly instead of send keys but findwindowEx is not recognizing the button in the dialogue box.

Comment: Send key to dialog box window?